# Get single element from JPA nested OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, querydsl

I have those Entities, It is not from real code, but it's not important I think.

```
    @Entity
    public class Country{

       private String name;
       //other fields with getters and setters
       @OneToMany
       private List<City> cites;


    }

    @Entity
    public class City {

       private String name;
        //other fields with getters and setters
       @OneToMany
       private List<Employee> emps;//list size could be millions


    }

     @Entity
     public class Employee {

        private String name;
        //other fields with getters and setters

       @OneToMany
       private List<Cars> cars;// list size could be 1000

    }


     @Entity
    public class Car {
      private String name;

      @ManyToOne
      private Employee emp;
    }
```

I would like to get single Car entity but with other data as well(Country, City, Employee) like this

1 Country in which 1 City in which 1 Empoyee in which 1 Car(which Id I put on select)

So when I do jpa joins from Country like

```
select c from Country c 
 inner join c.cites ci 
 inner join ci.emps em
  inner join ci.cars car where car.id = ?
```

I get ALL data in Country(with all cities).

What should I do to get 1 Country,1 City , 1 Employee, 1 Car.

If this is not possible to do with one jpa query then please suggest other way.

All relationships are bidirectional and lazy.

```
I tried this way. 
1)select car by id. then get Id of employee from car. 
2)select Employee by id - but at this point Employee data are nulls -
```

I think it is because ManyToOne from Car to Employee is lazy. What do you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the additional entities you want:

```
select c, ci, em, car from Country c 
inner join c.cites ci 
inner join ci.emps em
inner join ci.cars car where car.id = ?
```

Or, since your associations are bidirectional, select the car: it will have a ManyToOne to its employee, which will have a ManyToOne with its city, which will have a ManyToOne with its country:

```
select car from Car car where car.id = ?
```

or simply

```
em.find(Car.class, carId);
```

and now you can do

```
car.getEmployee().getCity().getCountry()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
For both solutions I have to do . 

emp.setCars(Collections.sigltonlist(car))
city.setEmps(Collections.singletonList(emp))
country.setCiyes(Collections.singletonList(city))

Otherwise during json serializtion all lazy collections get populated with millions of data. 

Also Second solution does not work when ManyToOne is Lazy (data are nulls in that case)

Comment: No, no, don't do that. Modifying a managed entity will automatically make the changes persistent in the database. You really don't want to remove all the cities of the country, etc. And even if the entity is not managed, then this simply shows a design problem in your app. What you're serializing to JSON is not a country with its cities. It's the result of a query, that contains a partial view of countries, cities, etc. Just create an appropriate class containing the data actual that you really want to serialize, and that is returned by your REST resource.

Comment: Thank you, I think after select entities are not managed - that is why I don't get update in DB. But I understand what you are saying. So in your opinion it it wrong to return Country with single city which contains single Employee. etc...

Comment: Yes. You're modifying the meaning of what the cities property of the class countries is supposed to represent: all the cities of the country. What you're returning shouldn't be a country.

Answer (score 2):

If all of the relationships are bidirectional then I would suggest starting from Car and then fetching up the hierarchy.

```
select c from Car car 
  inner join fetch car.emp emp
  inner join fetch emp.city city
  inner join fetch city.country country 
where car.id = ?
```

Just remember to add that `fetch` in all of the joins that you missed.

Comment: Thank you very much.
but I also have to do 

emp.setCars(Collections.sigltonlist(car))
city.setEmps(Collections.singletonList(emp))
country.setCiyes(Collections.singletonList(city))
Then only return county object from Spring controller

Otherwise during json serializtion all lazy collections get populated with millions of data